# Get records from a SQL table that should be there but are not

Tags: sql-server-2014

Is it possible to get a list of records that should be in a table but are not?

Here is the scenario: a survey question (caled certificate) is assigned to a number of facilities for a set period of time. Each facility is supposed to respond daily to this survey. The easy way to do this is to create/pre-populate the compliance records in a table and each time a facility responds, mark it as complete (set its ResponseDate). But because I am dealing with thousands of facilities over hundreds of days, it is not feasible. So right now I am doing this in DAL in a very inefficient way, converting the resulting datatable into JSON string and passing it to jQuery DataTable, and I am wondering if this can be achieved using a SQL query.

Here is an example:

Certificate: "Did you do this today"

5 facilities assigned to this certificate spanning May 1 to May 10. So there should be 50 compliance records in total.

This is how I have it set up in DB(just the releveant fields):

```
Table name: CertItems
CertiItemID    CertificateName  StartDate   EndDate
1               Cert1           05/01/2018  05/10/2018

Table name: FacilityCertificate:
FacCertificateID    FacilityID  CertItemID
1                   100          1
2                   200          1
3                   300          1
....                ...          ...
10                  1000         1

Table name: CertComplaince (theoretically, these records should be here, with some facilities having responded to some of the surveys) 
CertComplianceID    FacCertificateID    ResponseDueDate     ResponseDate
1                   1                   05/01/2018          05/01/2018
2                   1                   05/02/2018
3                   1                   05/03/2018          05/03/2018
...                 ...                 ...
10                  1                   05/10/2018
11                  2                   05/01/2018
12                  2                   05/02/2018          05/02/2018
13                  2                   05/03/2018
...                ...                  ...
20                 2                    05/10/2018
...                ...                  ...
98                 10                   05/08/2018          05/08/2018
99                 10                   05/09/2018
100                10                   05/10/2018
```

But becuase I cannot pre-populate this table, I enter a record each time a facility responds, so in reality it looks like this:

```
CertComplianceID    FacCertificateID    ResponseDueDate     ResponseDate
1                   1                   05/01/2018          05/01/2018
2                   1                   05/03/2018          05/03/2018
3                   2                   05/02/2018          05/02/2018
...                 ...                 ...                 ...
15                  10                  05/08/2018          05/08/2018
```

Question is how do I get all the records that would be in "theoretical" version of the compliance table having the table above, for a given date range. Something that includes facility ID, CertItemID/Name, ResponseDuedate and responseDate. I amusing SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Any SQL gurus/masters who can tell me yay or nay?